# Lipo Error: can't open input file

Tags: xcode, lipo

I'm getting this error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: /Users/snowcrash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awldrudjpictkjfutpthiwoocing/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApp.build/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp (No such file or directory)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is `lipo` being run?

Comment: Dunno. Is it not required then?

Comment: It's used to combine multi-arch binaries into a single binary.  I guess it depends on whether you support multiple arches.  Has it ever worked?

Comment: Yes. Currently, building for armv7 and armv7s.

Comment: Have you tried the usual, Clean project, delete derived data and snapshots, and the relaunching? Generally that fixes these sort of 'stuck' XCode issues.

Comment: Hmm... yes, several times. However, this last time fixed it!

Comment: This happened to me because I'm using cocoapods and the Pods project in the workspace had a different setting for "Build Active Architecture Only" than my main project (YES and NO respectively). When I set both to "NO" I was able to build and run on my device.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Project target-> Build setting-> Build Active Architecture only and set this Build Active Architecture only to YES. And it's working fine now..

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same problem. I was using cocoapods, and some other person committed the code after adding new pods with different cocoapods version.
you need to clean the project again installing the pods and run the xcode.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a stale library. I had `-xxxunusedlibrary` in 'Other linker flags' in Build Settings.

The library had been removed but the settings didn't clear automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem because command can't find the file generated by build. Please check whether your static library path is consistent with the command file path.